# Import configurable products through data profiles

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product, product-attribute

I have imported a configurable product through data profile for different stores view. For the model I exported one configurable product and edited it by adding separated lines for each store view. The products are imported almost fine.

I don't understand why I can't see configurable attributes for my product in frontend. When I try to edit the configurable product in admin it shows me

> Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available.

and I can choose some attributes like color and size. I will mention that my attributes have Scope - Global and Catalog Input Type is Dropdown.

My question is what have I done wrong? If I check my attributes than my product will be fine on frontend but I don't think this is the solution

Comment: Dataflow is old and slow, maybe it is buggy too. You should think about using ImportExport

Comment: How many lines does your CSV have?

Comment: For testing purpose I have only 10 lines(header + 9 lines for product). In the future I will have more products, all kind of products.

Comment: Hmm...I have just searched more info and it seems that by default configurable products can't be imported. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to import configurable products. It is very strange that if you export a configurable product, then delete it with all associated products and try to import the file you have exported earlier, you will get errors :) 
In order to be able to import I had to change the order in the CSV. First there must be simple products and after them the configurable product (reverse the default order from export)